# Specify Class file destination

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am trying to create a servlet. All my files are under the `src` folder. I am using `Eclipse

```
Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2`
```

However, when i select the servlet under the wizard, I keep getting the following screen

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: How do i get the next button to not gray out? As in, where do i specify the class file destination and why is it asking for that

Comment: Did you create a dynamic web project first?  A servlet has to exist within the context of some sort of web project.  You can't just create a standalone servlet class.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic web project needs to be created and not a basic Java project. Only then will the servlet be created. A Servlet cannot exist on its own outside a dynamic web project.